# Cannot access a server on Windows 10 using ssh key

Tags: networking, windows-10, ssh

I successfully connected to the server on Linux but I could not connect to the same server with the same ssh keys that I copied to my Windows 10 computer. I have already did a lot of research on forums regarding this problem but could not find the answer.

Here is the debug message that I get on Windows:

```
C:\Users\Valentin\.ssh>ssh XXXXXX -vvv
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\Valentin/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\Valentin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for
XXXXXX [Host]
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 111111 is address
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -A -W 111111
xxx.xxx@xxx.com -i C:\\Users\\Valentin\\.ssh\\id_rsa
debug3: spawning "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh -A -W 111111
xxx.xxx@xxx.com -i C:\\Users\\Valentin\\.ssh\\id_rsa"
CreateProcessW failed error:2
posix_spawn: No such file or directory
It says Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2 but I do not have this file at all. Is this mandatory to have (on Linux everything is running fine without it. In addition to that I already have the config file on my Windows)?
```

This is what my config file looks like:

```
C:\Users\Valentin\.ssh>type config
Host            XXXXXX
HostName        111111
User            xxx
ProxyCommand    ssh -A -W %h:%p xxx.xxx@xxx.com -i C:\Users\Valentin\.ssh\id_rsa
AddKeysToAgent  yes
IdentityFile    C:\Users\Valentin\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Obviously, I've got different Host, Hostname, etc. The ones here serve as examples. Please, note that I managed to run git clone on Windows using the ssh keys to verify that they work. So the problem is not in the keys - it's in the path, I predict.

NB: *PuTTY* is the last thing I want to use. First, I want to make sure there is a simpler way of doing this without installing any of additional software.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this.